# TaskCanceledException Results in Controller Action Being Called Again

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, task-parallel-library

I've got an ASP.NET Web API 2 controller action that uses [`HttpClient.PostAsync()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.postasync(v=vs.118).aspx) to make an upstream HTTP request.  If the upstream request, which is being awaited in the controller action, times out then a `TaskCanceledException` is thrown from the controller action.  At this point I'm seeing a few things I can't explain and could use some help:

1. **Global exception handling doesn't catch this exception**  If I surround the awaited `PostAsync()` call with try/catch I can catch the `TaskCanceledException`.  However, without try/catch, this exception **doesn't** appear in:

   - Global.asax.cs `Application_Error` method
   - `IExceptionLogger` or `IExceptionHandlers` add to the `HttpConfiguration.Services` in `WebApiConfig.cs`
2. **Controller Action is Invoked Again** - As I watch in Fiddler, there is only one request to the service made but a breakpoint set at the beginning of the controller action is hit multiple times, following each `TaskCanceledException` **until Fiddler stops awaiting a response and returns a 504 gateway error**.   It *seems* that something in the ASP.NET or Web API pipeline is handling the `TaskCanceledException` and **until the client (Fiddler, browser, etc) disconnects** is re-attempting to call my controller action.

At this point I know I can prevent the action from being re-tried by using try/catch and throwing an `HttpResponseException` or something but I'm particularly interested in why I can't catch this exception using normal means and why I'm seeing this apparent re-try behavior.  Any input is welcome!

## Minimal Repro

1. Add this Web API Controller to a project:

   ```
   namespace TaskRetryRepro.Controllers
   {
       using System;
       using System.Diagnostics;
       using System.Net.Http;
       using System.Threading;
       using System.Threading.Tasks;
       using System.Web;
       using System.Web.Http;

       public class ValuesController : ApiController
       {
           public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
           {
               // I see two lines output in my debug console per single request to this API action
               Debug.WriteLine(
                   "Get called with HttpRequestMessage: {0} and HttpContext.Current.Request: {1}", 
                   this.Request.GetHashCode(), 
                   HttpContext.Current.Request.GetHashCode());

               var httpClient = new HttpClient(new TimeoutHandler());

               // NOTE: No try/catch here
               await httpClient.GetAsync("http://www.google.com");

               return this.Ok(new[] { "value1", "value2" });
           }
       }

       /// <summary>The timeout handler.</summary>
       public class TimeoutHandler : DelegatingHandler
       {
           protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
           {
               // in my scenario calling another service it's an actual upstream service timeout but 
               // it throws the TaskCanceledException just the same
               Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
               var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage>();
               tcs.SetCanceled();
               return tcs.Task;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Clear your debug console
3. Issue a **SINGLE** request to the api action in a browser or via Fiddler e.g. GET `http://localhost:xxxxx/api/values`
4. Verify that output from the `Debug.WriteLine()` statement appears twice.  In my test I see something like this:

   `Get called with HttpRequestMessage: 30376100 and HttpContext.Current.Request: 37460558
   A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
   Get called with HttpRequestMessage: 12036987 and HttpContext.Current.Request: 42715336
   A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`

Comment: Could you post a minimal repro?

Comment: @StephenCleary thanks for taking a look.  I've added a repro as requested.

Comment: In that case, I recommend raising it on Microsoft Connect.

Comment: [MS Connect item #1029198](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1029198/apicontroller-actions-called-multiple-times-per-request-if-taskcanceledexception-is-thrown) created